# "Composition of an even and an odd function is even" means both $f(g(x))$ and "$g(f(x))$ are even?

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Basic_properties)

> composition of an even function and an odd function is even

Is "composition order" significant here?

Let $f(x)$ - *odd*, $g(x)$ - *even*

It means only $f(g(x))$ is sure to be even?

Or both "$f(g(x))$ is sure to be even" and "$g(f(x))$ is sure to be even" ?

P.S. When a mathematician says *"composition of F and G functions"* - is it always 100% unambiguous? What is it? G(F(x)) ?  First-mentioned function (F) is calculated first (so being "innermost")?

Comment: In theory, the order might matter to some authors and some readers. But you could just check and see whether it actually affects anything in this particular case.

Comment: Even one even function in any number of compositions of even odd functions will make the overall composition even...

Comment: In either case, it's even. 

$EO(-x)=E(O(-x))=E(-O(x))=E(O(x))=EO(x)$

$OE(-x)=O(E(-x))=O(E(x))=OE(x)$